# how to get a file path of wp-config.php of wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin in which i need to include config and query the wordpress database on click ..My question is 
How to get url of wp-config.php dynamically ..I have used

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php';
```

but i am getting error

```
include_once(): Failed opening /wp-config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

and i have tried many options like

```
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
require_once ("../wp-config.php");
```

I dunno wat is exact path ..

Any help is appreciated ..

Comment: Can you post the structure of your folders ?

Comment: lets assume its unknown ..i mean we can find the path dynamically then it wud be better..

Comment: can we find the path with any functions??

Comment: What do you trying to accomplish? And why do it dynamic when the file is always on the same spot?

Comment: dynamic means when this plugin is installed in any othr site ..it shud includ wp-config.php of tht site ..In this way i m talking dyanimic ..

Comment: But if you add an plugin to wordpress it allready have access to the wordpress database. I think you need to go back to the basics of wordpress plugin writing.

Comment: You *really don't want* to include wp-config in the middle of a plugin execution. Wherever you got this information, it is `doing_it_wrong()`. Maybe you're looking for Ajax, maybe you need some predefined functions to grab any WP url or path. But I really doubt you need wp-config. Research in [wordpress.se], lots of good info over there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you shouldn't be trying to include wp-config.php from your plugin.  There are few if any good reasons you would ever take this approach. Purists would go as far as to say it should never be done.

A WordPress plugin already has the proper context to access the global `$wpdb` variable for querying.  Take a look at this example:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}your_table WHERE column = %s", $your_value) );
```

Suggested reading:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 3):

Querying the database in WordPress should be done through the global $wpdb variable. See the codex entry for that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to avoid all the warnings to make good practices of coding, you can try this that include many paths where can find wp-config.php

```
if( !(include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php') )
if( !(include 'wp-config.php') )
if( !(include '../../../wp-config.php') )
if( !(include '../../../../wp-config.php') )
if( !(include '../../../../../wp-config.php') )
    die('<H1>Can\'t include config.</H1>');
```

Notes: 
you can add lines with `if( !(include 'my_custom_path/wp-config.php') )`

you can't use `wp_die()` until wp-config be included, then use php function `die()`